# Storing Location History in a Django Model Field

Tags: python, django, django-models, geodjango

I am trying to store a multiple locations in a field of a django model, but I am not quite sure how to go about it. I am using GeoDjango's `PointField` to store the latest reported location.

```
class Tracker(models.Model):
    # Other fields..

    # srid 4326 is the WGS84 Spheroid used by GPS
    current_pos = models.PointField(editable=True, srid=4326)
    pos_hist = ?
```

I have looked at apps like [`django-field-history`](https://github.com/grantmcconnaughey/django-field-history) and similar, but they seem to be designed to allow changes to be reversed by admin/user, which I don't need.

Another method seems to be using a `ForeignKey` to make a many-to-many relationship to a `Location` model, but I can't seem to get my head around how that would work as each `Tracker` would have multiple `Location` models in that field, but there would be multiple `Tracker`s?

Am I approaching this from the right direction or is there a better way?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You definitly want a `Location` model with a `ForeignKey` on `Tracker`.

Note that this will **not** create a "many to many" relationship but a "one-to-many" one where a `tracker` has many `locations` and a `location` belong to one single `tracker`.